# External Javascript Not Working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have just hit an odd problem with an external javascript file. It works perfectly in Edge and Chrome but not in Firefox (51.0.1).

I have a number of scripts at the bottom of the body of the page, like this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/adblocker.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dir_hotel').keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
            return false;
         }
    });
});
</script>
<?php if ($mobile_browser > 0) { ?>
<script>
/* MOBILE COLLAPSE MENU */
(function($) {
  $.fn.collapsable = function(options) {
    // iterate and reformat each matched element
    return this.each(function() {
      // cache this:
      var obj = $(this);
      var tree = obj.next('.nav');
      obj.click(function(){
        if( obj.is(':visible') ){tree.toggle();}
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slide-trigger').collapsable();
    $(".slide-trigger").click(function(){
        $('.slide-trigger').html($('.slide-trigger').text() == 'Collapse MENU' ? 'MENU' : 'Collapse MENU');
    });
});
</script>
<?php }?>
</body>
```

The adblocker.js file doesn't run. I've tried adding an alert as the first line of the .js file and the alert never appears. I've checked the console in the browser and that shows the file is not loading.

If I replace

```
<script src="js/adblocker.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('travins').clientHeight;
if (clientHeight < 20) {
        var node = document.getElementById("insnote");
        node.innerHTML = "<a href='https://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=18211&a=1906311&g=232597' target='_blank'>Columbus Direct Travel Insurance</a>";
}
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('flights').clientHeight;
if (clientHeight < 50) {
        var node = document.getElementById("flightnote");
        node.innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-7782323-11015988-1440520708000' target='_blank'>Skyscanner</a>";
}
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('carhire').clientHeight;
if (clientHeight < 20) {
        var node = document.getElementById("hirenote");
        node.innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.zestcarrental.com/click.php?adm=1018&adt=14' target='_blank'>Zest Car Rental</a>";
}
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('parking').clientHeight;
if (clientHeight < 20) {
        var node = document.getElementById("parknote");
        node.innerHTML = "<a href='https://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=20642&a=1906311&g=20842820' target='_blank'>Purple Parking</a>";
}
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('brittany').clientHeight;
if (clientHeight < 20) {
        var node = document.getElementById("ferrynote");
        node.innerHTML = "<a href='http://being.successfultogether.co.uk/click.asp?ref=731409&site=6792&type=b3&bnb=3' target='_blank'>Brittany Ferries</a>";
}
};
</script>
```

it works perfectly.

I've tried js/adblocker.js, /js/adblocker.js and mydomain.com/js/adblocker.js and that makes no difference. I've also double-checked that the file is actually uploaded, which it is. I must be doing something stupid, but what?

Comment: Do you have an adblocker extension installed in Firefox that's detecting `ad` in the name of the external script and blocking it?

Comment: Give that man a gold medal! You got it in one, Joe. I just renamed the file and it worked straight off. There's a little bit of double-checking to be absolutely sure, but I think you've got it. Ironic really, since the whole purpose of adblocker.js was to respond to the presence of an adblocker. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As Joe correctly suggested, the Adblock Plus extension was blocking the adblocker.js file. Changing the file name to blocker.js has solved the problem.

I have to say that I think this is a mighty crude way of filtering advertising, as there must be so many innocent ways that a file might have "ad" in the name. I'll be watching for this in future whenever my Firefox does something unexpected.

Comment: There certainly must be a better way but that's how everybody seems to be doing it. I have an extension to prevent sites from opening unrequested popups (some sites manage to skip the builtin feature) and I get a "Do not block ads" warning now and then (together with a bunch of ads, of course, since I'm not blocking them).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your JavaScript code between this codes 
 `(function($) { // your code here })(jQuery);`  in JavaScript file. It work with me.